# How to get validation for particulate fields on for submit event in Ext JS?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

Below is my code.
I get two fieldset each one contains some textboxes and a button.
I want to validate only those fields on button click that belongs to that field set.

For example, there are two options: Send SMS and Send Email. Each option has a send button. If I want to send either SMS or Email then I don't want to validate all fields. This means if I want to send Email then I want to validate only Emails Text fields, not SMS's fields on click of Send button of email.

Below is my code. You can understand better.

```
  this.form = new Ext.form.Panel({
            margin: '10 100 10 100',
            xtype: 'panel',
            border: true,
            layout: 'hbox',
            padding: '2 2 2 2',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'anchor',
                title: 'Send Email',
                //collapsible: true,
                //collapsed: true,
                border: false,
                defaults: { anchor: '100%' },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtRecipients',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Recipients email address',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtSubject',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Subject',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    name: 'txtMessage',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Type your message here',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 ',
                    rows: 4

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: '0 0 0 0',
                            text: 'Send',
                            width: 80,
                            height: 30,
                            handler: function () {
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }]

            },
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'anchor',
                title: 'Send SMS',
                //collapsible: true,
                //collapsed: true,
                border: false,
                defaults: { anchor: '100%' },

                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtRecipients',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Contact Numbers seperated by comma(,)',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    name: 'txt1Message',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Type your message here',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 ',
                    rows: 3

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'tbspacer',
                    height: 45
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            margin: '0 0 0 0',
                            text: 'Send',
                            width: 80,
                            height: 30,
                            handler: function () {
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }]

            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a specific function for each button. In each role you add the necessary validation to E-mail or SMS.

Example:

```
this.form = new Ext.form.Panel({
    margin: '10 100 10 100',
    xtype: 'panel',
    border: true,
    layout: 'hbox',
    padding: '2 2 2 2',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'anchor',
            title: 'Send Email',
            //collapsible: true,
            //collapsed: true,
            border: false,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtRecipients',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Recipients email address',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtSubject',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Subject',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    name: 'txtMessage',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Type your message here',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 ',
                    rows: 4

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        margin: '0 0 0 0',
                        text: 'Send',
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        handler: function() {
                            check_email();
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'anchor',
            title: 'Send SMS',
            //collapsible: true,
            //collapsed: true,
            border: false,
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    name: 'txtRecipients',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Contact Numbers seperated by comma(,)',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 '
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'textareafield',
                    name: 'txt1Message',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    //fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                    emptyText: 'Type your message here',
                    padding: '2 2 2 2 ',
                    rows: 3

                },
                {
                    xtype: 'tbspacer',
                    height: 45
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'button',
                        margin: '0 0 0 0',
                        text: 'Send',
                        width: 80,
                        height: 30,
                        handler: function() {
                            check_sms();
                        }
                    }]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});

function check_email(){
    // Here you do a validation of the E-mail fields
}

function check_sms(){
   // Here you do a validation of the SMS fields
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the fieldset xtype to form . so that you can directly validate and get values for SMS and email seperatly.